# Microsoft Webview 2 not downloading files

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8, webview2

i have an application, that uses webview 2 to download files. Although, when i open a link in the said webview 2 (added as a control to the form), it interrupts the download with a console log:

[0813/124939.884:ERROR:check.cc(307)] Check failed: false. NOTREACHED log messages are omitted in official builds. Sorry!
The program '[9772] testprogram.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

it does not throw an exception, the download fails to even start the download as even CoreWebView2_DownloadStarting didn't trigger

i am using the latest preview version of the edge, i have tried downgrading to a stable version but it did nothing.
Anyone seen this issue before? Why are exactly "NOTREACHED" downloads disabled, and can i somehow enable it?

Comment: You have to post your code, including the WebView2 initialization, when and where you're subscribing to the `DownloadStarting` event, whether you have set the `DefaultDownloadFolderPath` in the CoreWebView2 Profile, whether you're hiding the default dialog and how, if you're handling the progress of the operation (using other events). If possible, post the URL of the resource that fails, or describe its *nature*, e.g., it's a public resource over the Internet, a private network etc.